# Solr on low memory

Tags: memory, solr, requirements

Hi Guys :  I have a massive index that is useful for some data mining related tasks.  How slow is SOLR when it runs on a memory footprint that would be about 5% of the total index size ?  In general, are there guidelines for "what" SOLR  needs its memory for, and how much memory we generally should have for an index of a given size ?

Note that this index is unsharded and not necessary for super fast real time performance

Answer (score 2):

Lucene/Solr committer Grant Ingersoll has published a spreadsheet to compute disk and memory requirements for Solr. See http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2011/09/14/estimating-memory-and-storage-for-lucenesolr/.

Answer (score 0):

See if the below link is useful

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors